# Excel Pivot Table - Choose Which Column of labels to sum over

Tags: excel, pivot-table

The following data contains 5 columns of potential sets of figures I would like to sum over.

[image]

For instance, if I want to use Col 1 as the basis for a pivot table, I would want the total time spent between Oct 1 and Oct 6 for "Running", "Walking", "Flying", etc.

If I chose Col 2, I would want the total time over those dates that I spent doing the "slide", the "stroll", "flying" etc.

Is there a way to set up a pivot table so that I can specify, "use this column as a basis for summing this other set of columns"? Can the basis column be easily changed?

Comment: How do Col-1-thru-5 relate to 10/1-thru-10/6 ?  5 vs 6??  What do blanks in col1-5 mean?  Need more info on data in the table. If I chose col3, which values would be added up for Stroll?  which for Slide?  10+2.25+2.08+7.82+6.51+3.79?

Comment: Sounds like you want to use a `Calculated Field`

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using one of the first five columns at a time as a row field and all of the date columns as value fields.  It's not as pretty of a solution, but it works from what I can tell.